# Getting the cityname from lat/long in Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps

I can retrieve the lat/long from the following code. and based on this value i should able to get the city name.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

    <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else { 
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {

        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;


        var geocoder;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    var add= results[0].formatted_address ;
                    var  value=add.split(",");

                    count=value.length;
                    country=value[count-1];
                    state=value[count-2];
                    city=value[count-3];
                    alert("city name is: " + city);
                }
                else  {
                    alert("address not found");
                }
        }
         else {
            alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I read about Geo-location API from some of the articles. And i am not sure thats really needed as i am not implementing maps here. I just need only the present location city name

Comment: on your `showPosition` function you call `new google.maps.Geocoder()` as long as i know there's no `google` global variable in javascript

Comment: So. What do you suggest for the resolution

Comment: you need to implement `google map` so you can access `google` object

Answer (score 0):

Its depends on your purpose. If you want to use this application within a small area it is better to hard-code the city name and lat/long in a database, thereafter you can fetch the current lat/long and check for matches in your database for a percentage of accuracy. It depends on your need.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the response. So how can i do the percentage accuracy after getting lat/long of a current position

Comment: If you get the lat/long position from your database you can check them for a range. let lat/long from database is lat1, long 1 and lat/long for the current position lat and long. then you can check each of lat1, long1 from the database matches with (lat>=lat1-0.01 &&  lat <=lat1+0.01 && long>=long1-0.01 &&  long <=long1+0.01).  you can change the decimal value for your need of accuracy